# H1 margin unexpectedly overflows container

Tags: html, css

In the following snippet, why is the margin on the `h1` overflowing the top of `Console__Content`?

There is plenty of space in `Console__Content`, I would expect `h1` to be positioned so that I don't get the white band above the black rectangle.

What am I missing?

```css
.Container {
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.Console {
  height: 100%;
}

.Console__Content {
  font-family: monospace;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: black;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="Container">
  <div class="Console">
    <div class="Console__Content">
      <h1>Test!</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is caused by collapsing margins: https://www.sitepoint.com/collapsing-margins/

Comment: This is not same the other **Q** not a duplicate in my opinion.